# Is it possible to create linked selects in magento adminhtml?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there a way to create linked selects in Magento system.xml or adminhtml?

For example, if select1 contained countries, when a country is selected, select2 should display a list of regions in that country:

select1 = Australia
select2 = Queensland, New South Wales, etc.

or

select1 = England
select2 = Hampshire, Kent, Yorkshire, etc.

I've come across the `<depends>` option in xml, but this appears to rely on a single known static value to enable the second field, whereas I'm looking to make select2 populate based on the value chosen in select1.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way. Haven't actually tried this with select but I have with button_label. The idea is to create your own frontend_model (actually a block) and set there any template you want with your ajax code to populate the second select.
I believe you have such an example of a button in Mage_CatalogInventory at "Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart", but you should be able to modify it.